# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM identifier]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9f996a0'

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

The above error happens in this line:

```
  _nextRegionsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  [_nextRegionsArray addObject:_geofences_ending_regions[_positionOfRoute]];
```

where _nextRegionsArray is declared in here:

```
@implementation PSLocationManager
{
    NSMutableArray *_nextRegionsArray;
}
```

and geofences_ending_regions is an array containing CLRegions.

Why do I get that error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM identifier]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9f996a0'
```

Comment: Your error message says that you are sending an `identifier` message to your mutable array. That is not a valid message to send to an array. Nothing in your code examples indicates this. Your problem likely lies elsewhere. It would help immensely if you included more code. Barring that, search your code to see where you are sending the `identifier` message.

Answer (score 0):

The above exception is caused when the object to be added is nil. Can you verify if `_geofences_ending_regions[_positionOfRoute]` is not nil ?

Comment: yes it is not nil because i am using it in the previous lines of the code. I think that something is going on with the initialisation but I cannot find out what is wrong.